How to draw a ruler on a lightningchart
I want to draw a caliper on lightningchart, but I tried adding UIElement and found no way to implement it
chart
        .addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column, {
          x: this.chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
          y: this.chart.getDefaultAxisY(),
        })
        .setMouseInteractions(false)
        .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)
        .setMargin(5)
        .setEffect(false)

